# Why is James waiting with the Cleveland Cavaliers if he is a Rockets player?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> And should the Rockets manage to make it through that gauntlet, James and the Cleveland Cavaliers could be waiting to defend their title.

I don't understand why James who is a Rockets player are waiting with Cleveland Cavaliers.

Can you break down this sentence?

Source: [To Rule the NBA, James Harden Needed to Embrace Letting Go](http://time.com/4672996/james-harden-rule-nba/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For context, the article is about Houston Rockets point guard James Harden.

Notice that in formal writing, we refer to people by their last names. Throughout the article, James Harden is referred to as **Harden**. In "James and the Cleveland Cavaliers", James is also a last name, but it refers to [LeBron **James**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeBron_James) of the Cavaliers.

Comment: Could you please, answer one more question to confirm I'm understanding it right? 
"There are no shortage of explanations. Dwight Howard, an eight-time All-Star, left Houston in free agency, which some players credit with improving team chemistry. "

Comment: Could this mean some players think anyone in charge let Houston leave the team to improve teamwork?

Comment: No, I don't think so. When they say "left Houston", Houston refers to the team; they are the Houston Rockets (Rockets from the City of Houston). Howard left Houston (the Rockets). Some players acknowledge (= credit) his departure as the reason that the team chemistry (= teamwork, team relationships) improved.

Comment: But please, don't be afraid to post a new question. There is no problem if you make a new post. Just be sure to include your thoughts and identify the specific problem.

Comment: I thought Howard's(actually I confused Houston with Howard, sorry) departure contributed to the improvement of team's chemistry. But the improvement of team's chemistry was the reason of his departure?

Comment: Your first interpretation is almost the right idea. The sentence does not say that his departure contributed to the improvement of team chemistry. The sentences says that **some people believe** his departure contributed to the improvement of team chemistry. The bold part roughly means _to credit_.